# How to fetch all gallery image of mobile using cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I want to fetch the complete gallery of a mobile device to show them in a custom grid, is it possible? Right now I am using `$cordovaImagePicker` which is redirecting me to the gallery and then after selecting the image I am getting the Uri of that image. Instead of that I want the complete gallery images uri auto selected.

**`Controller`**

```
$scope.getImageFromGallery = function() {
    // Image picker will load images according to these settings
    var options = {
        maximumImagesCount: 1, // Max number of selected images, I'm using only one for this example
        width: 800,
        height: 800,
        quality: 80 // Higher is better
    };

    $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options).then(function(results) {
        // Loop through acquired images
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            alert(results);
            $scope.image = results[i];
            // Print image URI
        }
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error)); // In case of error
    });
}
```

Comment: yes ,for IOS and android and windows too :)

Comment: Similar unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997384/cordova-phonegap-photo-browser

Comment: @mayank did you get ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is to use [cordova-gallery-api](https://github.com/subitolabs/cordova-gallery-api) plugin, refer to the following example :

```
 galleryAPI.getAlbums(function(items)
{
    var html = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        var album = items[i];

        html += '<a href="javascript:loadAlbum(\'' + album.title + '\')" class="album"><span>' + escape(album.title) + '</span></a>';
    }

    $content.innerHTML = html;

}, function(error){alert(error);});

window.loadAlbum = function(albumName)
{
    galleryAPI.getMedia(albumName, function(items)
    {
        var html = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            var media = items[i];

            html += '<a href="javascript:void()" class="media"><img src="file://' + media.thumbnail + '" /></a>';
        }

        $content.innerHTML = html;

    }, function(error){alert(error);});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [this](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker) plugin,

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.images = [];
$scope.selectImages = function() {
    $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(
        function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                $scope.images.push(results[i]);
            }
            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        }
    );
};
```

**Html**

```
<div class="row responsive-md">
    <div class="col col-25" ng-repeat="image in images">
        <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" width="100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Tutorial**](http://www.gajotres.net/accessing-image-galery-using-ionic-and-ngcordova/)

Answer (score 0):

check this link, may be it is useful for you.

http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/photo-gallery-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile/

Comment: i will check and get back to you Thanks for your reply buddy :)